# vc-platform 3.58.0 : platform.blades.modules-list.labels.manual-install-disabled

Tags: virtocommerce

I just upgraded my website on Azure to vc-platform 3.58.0 and after that I see message "platform.blades.modules-list.labels.manual-install-disabled" in modules page. Can anyone suggest on how to enable manual module installation?

Thanks.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PsORi.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like scripts cached in your browser. Try to open your admin page in incognito mode. This error "platform.blades.modules-list.labels.manual-install-disabled" removed in platform v.3.56., so if the problem is not gone, please create the issue on the GitHub https://github.com/VirtoCommerce/vc-platform/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&template=bug_report.md

Comment: It worked in incognito mode. Thank you. It helps and allows me move forward.. But whatever I do on regular browser it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

1. Please try to refresh client scripts in the browser by pressing Ctrl+F5 or clear browser scripts cache any other way.
2. Ensure appsettings.json does not contain *RefreshProbingFolderOnStart* key set to false.

Comment: I had the same problem and the refresh cache in the browser as Andrei suggested, resolve the issue. If you still the problem, could you contact with our support: https://help.virtocommerce.com/support/home, The team will organize a support session with you.